How to make tesseract (pytesseract) recognise '±'?
Plus or minus character
I'm trying to detect text (mostly numbers) from an image (technical diagram). Do I need to train (if yes, how) tesstrain? jtessboxeditor?
On doing the OCR from a set of coordinates, I get 3+.045 instead of 3±.045 for all the cases there's '±'.
reprex:
import json
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd

# Sample JSON data
json_data = '''
[
    {"box": [10, 20, 100, 50]},
    {"box": [150, 30, 200, 80]},
    {"box": [-10, -20, 50, 30]},
    {"box": [1000, 1000, 1100, 1100]}
]
'''

# Create a sample image
image = cv2.imread('path_to_sample_image.jpg')  # Replace with an actual image path
image_height, image_width = image.shape[:2]

# Function to crop image and perform OCR with boundary check
def crop_and_ocr_with_boundary_check(image, coordinates, image_width, image_height):
    ocr_results = []
    skipped_coordinates = []
    for i, (x1, y1, x2, y2) in enumerate(coordinates):
        original_coords = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
        x1 = max(0, min(x1, image_width - 1))
        y1 = max(0, min(y1, image_height - 1))
        x2 = max(0, min(x2, image_width))
        y2 = max(0, min(y2, image_height))

        if x2 - x1 < 5 or y2 - y1 < 5:
            skipped_coordinates.append((i, original_coords, "Too small"))
            continue

        cropped_img = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_img)
        ocr_results.append({
            "coordinates": (x1, y1, x2, y2),
            "text": text.strip()
        })

    return ocr_results, skipped_coordinates

# Main execution
annotations = json.loads(json_data)
coordinates = [annotation["box"] for annotation in annotations]

ocr_results, skipped_coordinates = crop_and_ocr_with_boundary_check(image, coordinates, image_width, image_height)

ocr_df = pd.DataFrame(ocr_results)

print(f"Total annotations in JSON: {len(annotations)}")
print(f"Total OCR results: {len(ocr_results)}")
print(f"Skipped coordinates: {len(skipped_coordinates)}")
for skip in skipped_coordinates:
    print(f"  Index: {skip[0]}, Coordinates: {skip[1]}, Reason: {skip[2]}")

print(ocr_df)

print(f"Image dimensions: {image_width}x{image_height}")


Try adding it to a character whitelist with  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_img, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=':±. =_+- 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' ")
